# Help required with BizTalk mapping

Tags: c#, biztalk

I am trying to get the data from input xml message using functoids. But this doesn't seem to work. Below is my XML snippet

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<ROOT>
    <COMPANIES>
        <COMPANY>
            <NAME>FOO CORP</name>
        </COMPANY>
        <COMPANY>
            <NAME>ACME CORP</name>
        </COMPANY>
    </COMPANIES>
    <INFORMATIONS>
        <INFORMATION>
            <TESTING>
                <TESTS>
                    <NAME>1221</NAME>
                    <TEST>
                        <TEXT>I AM SAM</TEXT>
                    </TEST>
                </TESTS>
                <TESTS>
                    <NAME>21</NAME>
                    <TEST>
                        <TEXT>FADFDF</TEXT>
                    </TEST>
                </TESTS>
                <TESTS>
                    <NAME>3001</NAME>
                    <TEST>
                        <TEXT>SGFGSDFG</TEXT>
                    </TEST>
                </TESTS>
                <TESTS>
                    <NAME>4569</NAME>
                    <TEST>
                        <TEXT>12312</TEXT>
                    </TEST>
                </TESTS>
            </TESTING>
        <INFORMATION>
    </INFORMATIONS>
</ROOT>
```

1. First I am trying to loop through COMPANY and get the NAME "ACME CORP". but which ever functoid i use (scripting, string extract etc) I always get the FOO CORP. I even tried inline XSLT but that also doesn't seem to work. Any idea how to get the 2nd COMPANY name?
2. Secondly, I have mapped `<TEXT>` directly to `<node>` in my destination schema. What i get is only 2 values from `<TEXT>`. Not all the `<TEXT>` are mapped to my `<node>`.  Output i am getting is
   I don't get is

   I AM SAM
   FADFDF

I don't get

```
<node>SGFGSDFG</node>
<node>12312</node>
```

Any one knows how i could get the values?

Thanks in advance

cheers,

Karthik

Comment: Please add your destination schema and/or your desired output for your sample document.

Comment: this is only a dummy xml file i created based on my original input file. Problem is I cannot share the original file. Structure wise both are same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1: How to get the `NAME` of the **second** `COMPANY`?

1) Add **Iteration** functoid (Advanced Functoids) and connect to `COMPANY` node in your source schema

2) Add **Equal** functiod (Logical Functoids) and connect to **Iteration** functoid

3) Configure **Equal** functoid; add constant value `2`

4) Add **Value Mapping (Flattening)** functoid (Advanced Functoids)

5) Connect output of **Equal** to input of **Value Mapping**

6) Connect `NAME` emlement of source schema to input of **Value Mapping**

7) Connect output of **Value Mapping** to destination schema element

---

Q2: Not all source `TEXT` elements are transformed to destination `node`

This seems to be a side effect of your mapping concering Q1 and I cannot reproduce your error.

Check minOccurs and maxOccurs of your source and destination schema for the elements/nodes in question.

Comment: Nevermind. It worked. Thanks a lot. My first problem is sovled.

Comment: Any idea about the second part?

Comment: @Karthik I tested like you described (direkt link source `TEXT` and destination `node`) and all 4 values from your sample are transformed to the destination document. I suspect the problem is in your destination schema or your map is messed up. You could try to delete the generated <YourMapName>.btm.cs code file and see if the problem persists.

Comment: The direct mapping didn't work. Also i don't have the mapname.btm.cs

Comment: @Karthik Okay, if you don't have the .btm.cs code file you didn't build your project yet - so we can rule out that any of your previous attempts cause this issue.

Comment: @Karthik It's really hard to tell without seeing the actual source and target schema of the affected nodes. Could add just those parts from your real schemas?